# Product Subscription - Autoship

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I am looking for the best way to support product autoship / subscription which has a validity period (start, end date and shipping interval - (e.g 1 month) and associated product

Customer can subscribe to product autoship.

Products in the customer's order are grouped within the fulfillment group if they share the same autoship the customer has subscribed to.

On every autoship date, the same order is generated in the background.

Suggestions are much appreciated,
Thanks,
Milan

Answer (score 2):

Broadleaf provides an enterprise-compatible module called `Subscription` that meets these requirements.

If you are looking for something in regards to community edition, you would have to make custom changes.

From a high level, you would want to do the following:

1. Some indication on your `Product` or `Sku` that indicates it is compatible with autoship / subscription.
2. An entity that holds the fields that you mentioned - start, end date, shipping interval, and also order, customer, customer payment, and status.
3. During checkout, add a new activity at the end of `blCheckoutWorkflow` that checks for compatible order items to create your "autoship" entity.
4. You will need to create some cron job or quarts scheduler that can trigger events. Sounds like you might want this to be set to a daily recurrence. This is provided in enterprise licenses, but you will have to do something custom for community.
5. Create an endpoint or service that the job/scheduler calls when triggered.
6. In your endpoint, you will want to create a new workflow with a set of activities. These activities will need to:

   - Prepare a new order by copying the required entities of the existing order from the "autoship" entity.
   - Trigger the `blCheckoutWorkflow` with your newly created order.
   - Update the "autoship" entity depending on success of the attempted payment.

This should get you to a good place given the requirements.